# Google docs, how to show an H1 heading always at the top of a new page?

Tags: google-docs

Trying to find a way how to show an H1 heading always at the top of a new page, not sure if this is possible.

I have multiple H1 headings and they can be pushed downwards rather that they will stick to the top of each page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106999/88163)

Comment: Related: [a](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113920/88163)

Answer (score 2):

1. Highlight the heading
2. Click "format" in the main toolbar and hover over "Line and paragraph spacing"
3. At the very bottom of the list, select "add page break before"
4. If you wish to have this applied to all headings of the same type, hover over "heading x" in styles and select "update 'heading x' to match"

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking to "freeze" a row in place as you scroll down a spreadsheet? If so:

> To pin data in the same place and see it when you scroll, you can freeze rows or columns.
>
> 1. On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> 2. Select a row or column you want to freeze or unfreeze.
> 3. At the top, click `View` > `Freeze`.
> 4. Select how many rows or columns to freeze.
>
> To unfreeze, select a row or column. Then, at the top, click `View` > `Freeze` > `No rows` or `No columns`.

Source: [Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9060449?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Comment: This questions is about Google Documents, not about Google Sheets, the later hasn't H1 headings.